# SOLR 3.5 Substring match with EdgeNGramFilter

Tags: solr

The following is the new field type I use for autocomplete purposes:

```
<fieldType name="autocomplete_edge" class="solr.TextField">
   <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="30" minGramSize="2"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And the field definition is as follows:

```
<field name="title" type="autocomplete_edge" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

My problem is that, let's say the indexed field text is:

"the lord of the rings"

My goal is that SOLR can return this document with all of the following queries:

query-1: title:"th"
query-2: title:"the lor"
query-3: title:"lord of"
query-4: title:"the rin"

etc.

While analyzing the resulting index after tokenizing and filtering by EdgeNGram I saw that the indexed terms are as follows:

"th" "the" "lo" "lor" "lord" "of" "th" "the" "ri" "rin" "ring" "rings"

Therefore the query "lord of" matches but the query "the rings" does not.

I am aware that for indexing (performance and disk space) keeping all possible combinations of the edged ngrams is expensive, however for the application we must do it.

Any possible solutions are welcome.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The query `the rings` should match.

EdgeNGramFilterFactory will generate edgegrams, however the edge grams generated have the same position.

So if you check the tokens generated by edge gram would have the same position.

th, the -> 1
lo, lor, lord -> 2
th, the -> 3
ri, rin, ring, rings -> 4

So the query `lord of` as well as `the rings` should match the searched field as they are next to each other.

Check using debug if the query is searching on the same field.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, checking again, it matches the query "the lo" but not "the lor" or "the lord". And, the query is searching on the same field.

Comment: whats the field definition ?? can you add to your question ?

Comment: I have added the field definition to the question. While querying, I send the query as title:"query" format to SOLR.

Comment: I put quotes, without quotes it searches for the and lord seperately. It makes an OR query.

Comment: yup .. it should match ideally will test and repost. Is the indexed value just the lord of the rings or much longer.

Comment: Looking the indexes with luke, value is just the lord of the rings. Besides, I analyzed whether it has generated edgeNgrams and the answer is yes. It seems that unlike you say the position of the ngrams are not the same or I am doing something wrong. Anyway, I will try to solve the problem. Thanks for help.

Comment: i am able to query and match the results with partial words as well e.g. query q=title_autocomplete_edge:"th lor of th rin" . Can you reload the cores and reindex and query again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33081/discussion-between-messe-and-jayendra)